# Setting composer (airflow) bucket using gcloud CLI

Tags: airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer, gcloud-cli

I've been creating a composer environment using the console interface, and then setting three variables using the cli (using examples from the QuickStart doc):

```
gcloud composer environments run etl --location europe-west1 variables -- --set gcp_project projectname
gcloud composer environments run etl --location europe-west1 variables -- --set gcs_bucket gs://bucketname
gcloud composer environments run etl --location europe-west1 variables -- --set gce_zone europe-west1-b
```

This doesn't set the bucket for some reason, but all three variables appear under `Admin > Variables`

I was hoping to combine all this into one step, and set the composer bucket too - so built the following CLI command:

```
gcloud composer environments create etl --location=europe-west1 --env-variables=gcp_project=projectname,gcs_bucket=gs://bucketname,gce_zone=europe-west1-b --service-account=serviceemail --zone=europe-west1-b
```

But this doesn't set the bucket and doesn't even create the variables.

How do I kick off a composer environment from the CLI with the bucket name and variables set?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do with the GCS bucket? Note that Airflow variables and environment variables are two different concepts: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#setting_airflow_variables.

Comment: If I can specify the bucket, I can point it to one with my DAG scripts in

Comment: Unfortunately Composer doesn't support user-provided GCS bucket, each Composer environment comes with its own new GCS bucket.

Comment: Oh well! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer doesn't support user-provided GCS bucket, each newly created environment comes with its own GCS bucket.